# How to perform pslda in R showing error rate for several elements of a list?

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

I am performing a splsda-model in R on 10 dataframes (data of 10 study areas), stored as a list (`datalist`). All these dataframes are similar, with the same variables, but just different values.
I use the micromics library to do this.

This is the head of the first study area. It compares the absence or presence of wetlands (factor variable - wetl or no wetl) depending on its value of TPI of different ranges.

```
> head(datalist[[1]])
  OID POINTID WETLAND TPI200 TPI350 TPI500 TPI700 TPI900 TPI1000 TPI2000 TPI3000 TPI4000 TPI5000 TPI2500
1  -1       1 no wetl     70     67     55     50     48      46      53      47      49      63      48
2  -1       2 no wetl     37     42     35     29     32      16      17      35      49      63      26
3  -1       3 no wetl     45     55     45     39     41      41      53      47      49      63      48
4  -1       4 no wetl     46     58     51     43     46      36      54      47      49      62      49
5  -1       5 no wetl     58     55     53     49     47      46      54      47      49      62      49
6  -1       6 no wetl     56     53     51     49     46      46      54      47      49      61      49
```

I have done the cross validation step using following code:

```
library(mixOmics)

for (i in 1: length(model_list))
{
  myperf_plsda <- perf(model_list[[i]], validation = "Mfold", folds = 10, 
                            progressBar = FALSE, nrepeat = 10, auc = TRUE)
  save(myperf_plsda, file="performancePLSDA.RData")
}
```

`model_list` is the list obtained from the spslda-function.

But now I am stuck in the next step, which is to look at the error rate (overall and per class)

For just one dataframe (studyarea), I can use the **following code**:

```
# cross-validation error in function of nr of PCs
# can see how many PCs is best
plot(myperf_plsda, col = color.mixo(5:7), sd = TRUE, 
     legend.position = "horizontal")

# error rate overall and per class
myperf_plsda$error.rate
myperf_plsda$error.rate.class
myperf_plsda$auc
```

So **first**, I am trying to plot see the error in function of the prinipal components (= plot, first code here above for one study area). The result would be something like [image: this] I would like to have it in a pdf.

**Second**, I want to know the overall error rate and error rate per class, from which the code is mentioned above for one study area. The result for one study area is then for example:

- overall error rate: [image: overall error rate]
- error rate per class: [image: error rate per class]

I have tried some ways to all this codes in a `for` loop, or using `lapply`, in order to get these results for the 10 study areas.

, such as:

```
### To see how many PCs is best ###
pdf('overallerrorrate_wetlall_small.pdf')
for (i in 1:length(myperf_plsda))
{
plot(model_list[[i]], col = color.mixo(5:7), sd = TRUE, 
     legend.position = "horizontal")
}
dev.off()
```

or

```
for (i in 1:length(myperf_plsda))
  {plot(myperf_plsda, col = color.mixo(5:7), sd = TRUE, 
     legend.position = "horizontal")}
```

or

```
for (i in 1:length(myperf_plsda))
{myperf_plsda[[1]]error.rate
  myperf_plsda[[1]]error.rate.class
  myperf_plsda[[i]]auc
}
```

or

```
lapply(myperf_plsda, [[, 'error.rate')`
```

But all these codes don't work! How can I run the code for multiple elements in a list? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you speak as to what does not work? It seems to me like you're trying to plot. What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I added extra information about the expected results in the post. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your outputs, you will have to create a new list and save the results on it. Using just `myperf_plsda` could be overwriting each step in the loop. Also most of the measures you want are lists, so I added some processing functions to reach dataframes. I used next dummy data:

```
library(mixOmics)
#Function
custom_splsda <- function(datalist, ncomp, keepX, ..., Xcols, Ycol){
  Y <- datalist[[Ycol]]
  X <- datalist[Xcols]
  res <- splsda(X, Y, ncomp = ncomp, keepX = keepX, ...)
  res
}
#Data
datalist <- list(df1 = structure(list(OID = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), POINTID = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6), WETLAND = c("no wetl", "no wetl", "no wetl", 
"wetl", "wetl", "wetl"), TPI200 = c(70, 37, 45, 46, 58, 56), 
    TPI350 = c(67, 42, 55, 58, 55, 53), TPI500 = c(55, 35, 45, 
    51, 53, 51), TPI700 = c(50, 29, 39, 43, 49, 49), TPI900 = c(48, 
    32, 41, 46, 47, 46), TPI1000 = c(46, 16, 41, 36, 46, 46), 
    TPI2000 = c(53, 17, 53, 54, 54, 54), TPI3000 = c(47, 35, 
    47, 47, 47, 47), TPI4000 = c(49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49), TPI5000 = c(63, 
    63, 63, 62, 62, 61), TPI2500 = c(48, 26, 48, 49, 49, 49)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"), df2 = structure(list(OID = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1), POINTID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), WETLAND = c("no wetl", 
"no wetl", "no wetl", "wetl", "wetl", "wetl"), TPI200 = c(70, 
37, 45, 46, 58, 56), TPI350 = c(67, 42, 55, 58, 55, 53), TPI500 = c(55, 
35, 45, 51, 53, 51), TPI700 = c(50, 29, 39, 43, 49, 49), TPI900 = c(48, 
32, 41, 46, 47, 46), TPI1000 = c(46, 16, 41, 36, 46, 46), TPI2000 = c(53, 
17, 53, 54, 54, 54), TPI3000 = c(47, 35, 47, 47, 47, 47), TPI4000 = c(49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49), TPI5000 = c(63, 63, 63, 62, 62, 61), TPI2500 = c(48, 
26, 48, 49, 49, 49)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Now the code, I will create an empty list `myperf_plsda`:

```
#Create model_list, you must have the object created
model_list <- lapply(datalist, custom_splsda,
                     ncomp = 2, keepX = c(5, 5),
                     Xcols = 4:8, Ycol = "WETLAND")
#Create empty list
myperf_plsda <- list()
#Loop for objects and saving
for (i in 1: length(model_list))
{
  myperf_plsda[[i]] <- perf(model_list[[i]], validation = "Mfold", folds = 3, 
                       progressBar = FALSE, nrepeat = 3, auc = TRUE)
  object <- myperf_plsda[[i]]
  save(object,file = paste0("performancePLSDA.",i,".RData"))
}
#Process the object myperf_plsda
#First function to get elements
extract1 <- function(x)
{
  #Object
  error.rate <- x$error.rate
  error.rate <- lapply(error.rate, as.data.frame)
  #Process
  O1 <- do.call(rbind,error.rate)
  #Separate vars
  O1$id <- rownames(O1)
  rownames(O1) <- NULL
  O1$id1 <- gsub("\\..*","", O1$id )
  O1$id2 <- gsub(".*\\.","", O1$id )
  O1$id <- NULL
  return(O1)
}
#Function 2
extract2 <- function(x)
{
  #Object
  error.rate.class <- x$error.rate.class
  names(error.rate.class) <- gsub('.','_',names(error.rate.class),fixed = T)
  error.rate.class <- lapply(error.rate.class, as.data.frame)
  #Process
  O2 <- do.call(rbind,error.rate.class)
  #Separate vars
  O2$id <- rownames(O2)
  rownames(O2) <- NULL
  O2$id1 <- gsub("\\..*","", O2$id )
  O2$id2 <- gsub(".*\\.","", O2$id )
  O2$id <- NULL
  return(O2)
}
#Function 3
extract3 <- function(x)
{
  #Object
  auc <- x$auc
  #Modify for dataframe
  change <- function(x)
  {
    y <- as.data.frame(x)
    y$id1 <- rownames(y)
    rownames(y)<-NULL
    y$id1 <- gsub('.','_',y$id1,fixed = T)
    return(y)
  }
  auc <- lapply(auc, change)
  #Process
  O3 <- do.call(rbind,auc)
  #Separate vars
  O3$id2 <- rownames(O3)
  rownames(O3) <- NULL
  O3$id2 <- gsub("\\..*","", O3$id2 )
  return(O3)
}
#Apply functions and save in lists for late process
L1 <- lapply(myperf_plsda,extract1)
L2 <- lapply(myperf_plsda,extract2)
L3 <- lapply(myperf_plsda,extract3)
#Assign the same names from model_list
names(L1) <- names(model_list)
names(L2) <- names(model_list)
names(L3) <- names(model_list)
#Bind the data
#Error rate
error.rate.df <- do.call(rbind,L1)
error.rate.df$genid <- gsub("\\..*","", rownames(error.rate.df) )
rownames(error.rate.df) <- NULL
#Error rate class
error.rate.class.df <- do.call(rbind,L2)
error.rate.class.df$genid <- gsub("\\..*","", rownames(error.rate.class.df) )
rownames(error.rate.class.df) <- NULL
#Auc
auc.df <- do.call(rbind,L3)
auc.df$genid <- gsub("\\..*","", rownames(auc.df) )
rownames(auc.df) <- NULL
```

With previous code you will end up with three dataframes that contains the values that are identified according to names of `model_list`, you can navigate by vars `id1`, `id2` and `genid` to see measures, components and datasets:

```
error.rate.df

   max.dist centroids.dist mahalanobis.dist     id1   id2 genid
1 0.2222222      0.2222222        0.2222222 overall comp1   df1
2 0.2777778      0.3888889        0.2777778 overall comp2   df1
3 0.2222222      0.2222222        0.2222222     BER comp1   df1
4 0.2777778      0.3888889        0.2777778     BER comp2   df1
5 0.2222222      0.2222222        0.2222222 overall comp1   df2
6 0.2777778      0.3333333        0.2777778 overall comp2   df2
7 0.2222222      0.2222222        0.2222222     BER comp1   df2
8 0.2777778      0.3333333        0.2777778     BER comp2   df2

error.rate.class.df

       comp1     comp2              id1     id2 genid
1  0.3333333 0.3333333         max_dist no wetl   df1
2  0.1111111 0.2222222         max_dist    wetl   df1
3  0.3333333 0.6666667   centroids_dist no wetl   df1
4  0.1111111 0.1111111   centroids_dist    wetl   df1
5  0.3333333 0.3333333 mahalanobis_dist no wetl   df1
6  0.1111111 0.2222222 mahalanobis_dist    wetl   df1
7  0.3333333 0.3333333         max_dist no wetl   df2
8  0.1111111 0.2222222         max_dist    wetl   df2
9  0.3333333 0.5555556   centroids_dist no wetl   df2
10 0.1111111 0.1111111   centroids_dist    wetl   df2
11 0.3333333 0.3333333 mahalanobis_dist no wetl   df2
12 0.1111111 0.2222222 mahalanobis_dist    wetl   df2

auc.df

           x      id1   id2 genid
1 0.62966667 AUC_mean comp1   df1
2 0.06414361   AUC_sd comp1   df1
3 0.81483333 AUC_mean comp2   df1
4 0.06414361   AUC_sd comp2   df1
5 0.62966667 AUC_mean comp1   df2
6 0.06414361   AUC_sd comp1   df2
7 0.77780000 AUC_mean comp2   df2
8 0.11110000   AUC_sd comp2   df2
```

Finally for the plots you can use next code (I have assigned the name of the dataset to x label so you can identify it into the plots):

```
#Plot and save
#Assign names
names(myperf_plsda) <- names(model_list)
pdf('example.pdf')
for (i in 1:length(myperf_plsda))
{
  plot(myperf_plsda[[i]], col = color.mixo(5:7), sd = TRUE, 
       legend.position = "horizontal",xlab = paste0(names(myperf_plsda)[i],' (Comp)'))
}
dev.off()
```

As remark, I have changed the number of folds in order to make the code working but with your real data you could set the original values you have.

Comment: Hi Duck, this helps! This is already the third time you help me out! A HUGE thank you, hero!!